# Flag based on Language and Two Factor Authentication

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, development, plugin, system-plugin

In a system plugin I need to have two flags, one to check if there are more than one language in administration and another flag to check if a two factor authentication is needed.

Tried the following script and it is working, but I would like to know if there is a better/recommended way of doing it.

```
// Check more than 1 installed language
jimport('joomla.language.helper');
$langs = JLanguageHelper::createLanguageList(null, JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, false, true);
$flagLang  = (count($langs) > 1) ? true : false;

// Check two factor authentication need
FOFPlatform::getInstance()->importPlugin('twofactorauth');
$factor = FOFPlatform::getInstance()->runPlugins('onUserTwofactorIdentify', array());
$flagFactor  = (!empty($factor)) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is better way for getting `$flagFactor`.

```
$flagFactor = JPluginHelper::isEnabled('twofactorauth');
```

This returns `true` if any of `twofactorauth` type plugins is enabled and accessible by current user or guest. False otherwise.

And your `? true : false` is redundant, since `(count($langs) > 1)` returns `boolean` and therefore already equals to `true` or `false`.

```
// Check more than 1 installed language
jimport('joomla.language.helper');
$langs    = JLanguageHelper::createLanguageList(null, JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, false, true);
$flagLang = (count($langs) > 1); // boolean

// Check two factor authentication need
$flagFactor = JPluginHelper::isEnabled('twofactorauth'); // boolean
```